# Is/Was there anything offensive about asking this conjoined twins question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, etiquette

[What is the halachic status of adult conjoined twins?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30887/what-is-the-halachic-status-of-adult-conjoined-twins)

---

## Background in Christianity SE

I'm Catholic. It occurred to me recently I never bothered to look this up for the case of 1 set of reproductive organs. I tried asking this in Christianity SE [Conjoined twins and marriage and sex](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/93397/conjoined-twins-and-marriage-and-sex) And then I was accused of lechery LOL. I talk about it in [this revision](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/revisions/93397/5):

There's a deleted comment that said I was lecherous or something unless I was actually 1 of the conjoined twins or 1 of the prospective partners. The comment made it seem like I have a fantasy of having sex with conjoined twins. Lol. I counter-argued that I'm no different from someone in the early 1500s asking 'Can Henry VIII marry his brother's widow?'

10 hours ago I submitted this comment flag quoting [Terry Tao](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/67473):

> [So one should be unafraid to ask “stupid” questions, challenging conventional wisdom on a subject; the answers to these questions will occasionally lead to a surprising conclusion, but more often will simply tell you why the conventional wisdom is there in the first place, which is well worth knowing.](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-and-answer-them/)

But it was declined. LOL.

7 hours ago Ken Graham♦ said

> I lean towards closing this question on a philosophical basis since the Catholic Church would not condone such sex that shared the same sexual organs (vagina) in conjoined twins. Common sense tells us that it would not be morally permitted. The sharing of the same vagina by two different males would never be permitted; it is that simple. Medical professionals may or may not be able to inform us as to which twin controls the reproductive organs. Until this is verified, I do not see a positive outcome for any marriage at all being permitted. Finding info on such cases is impossible to find.

---

## Judaism SE

I looked it up in Judaism SE, and it turns out not only is the question almost a decade old and without downvotes but also does it look like no one was ever offended by this question.

[What is the halachic status of adult conjoined twins?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30887/what-is-the-halachic-status-of-adult-conjoined-twins)

Is/Was there anything offensive about asking this conjoined twins question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi Yodeya's [official scope description](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) includes the following rule on modesty:

> Please respect that in the Jewish tradition certain questions, especially certain questions relating to sexuality, are discussed only in private. Such questions will be closed or deleted at the discretion of the moderators or community. ([Source](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/123/how-modest-should-this-site-be/125#comment-206))

Please see the Meta post linked there and other Meta posts linked to it for more discussion of this rule. The bottom line is that we have never adopted a bright-line rule regarding what is and is not acceptable in sexuality-related posts, so they are dealt with on a case-by-case basis, based on the judgement of the community and the moderators.

The [existing Mi Yodeya question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30887/what-is-the-halachic-status-of-adult-conjoined-twins) does seem to me (and as you observe, to a decade of community observation) unobjectionable on modesty grounds. A hypothetical question that goes into more depth regarding anatomical configurations and contact would certainly be closer to the line. However, how the community and moderators would handle it depends very much on the specifics of what's in it and how it's written.

Each Stack Exchange community has its own rules regarding scope and content, and there's no necessity that any two maintain equivalent standards. It can be worthwhile for communities to learn about and from other communities' policies, but such exploration is most likely to be productive outside the context of argument about a specific post.

Comment: ok fine thanks for your honesty and empathy Isaac Moses. Re 'A hypothetical question that goes into more depth regarding anatomical configurations and contact would certainly be closer to the line.' ok that's fair so could i ask the same anatomic hypotheticals here in judaism SE (assuming they're not answered already? or are they?) ?

Comment: Please see the following sentence in my answer.

Comment: right ok then soooo as for the specifics, you know Gasai what's in there: i already said the [scenarios](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/93411/conjoined-twins-with-1-set-of-reproductive-organs-is-there-any-denomination-tha) - so can i? or do i have to make another meta post for this?

Comment: If you write the post, the community and moderators will decide what to do with it based on what's in it. My expectation, based on what I've seen so far, is that it would be a lot more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Isaac Moses ok lol thanks. actually my main purpose in asking is to find out if it was already covered in the previous question because even the english parts there read Greek to me. Judaism sure is a very different religion from Christianity apparently. I read about the apparent differences before, but this is the 1st time I'm seeing the differences 1st hand.

Comment: @BCLC it does look like the issue was covered in the previous question. Based on the answers there, it appears the specifics of anatomy don't matter much (except, possibly, if they shared one head).